# Capacitor Preferences Plugin - Can get Capacitor/Console value but DevTools value is null

Tags: reactjs, sharedpreferences, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I'm saving some values such as roomName (e.g.:A206), language (e.g.:English), mail (e.g.:abc@mail.com), calendar (e.g.: MainUI) to SharedPreferences, I gave WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions too. I want to get those values via capacitor preferences plugin on react side.

I applied documentation like this

```
 async function fetchValueFromPreferences(key) {
    console.log("preference key", key);
    const { value } = await Preferences.get({ key: key });
    return value;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const fetchArray = ["roomName", "language", "calendar", "mail"];
      for (const item of fetchArray) {
        const value = await fetchValueFromPreferences(item);
        if (value !== null && item === "roomName") {
          console.log("Shared preferences roomName value:", value);
          setMeetingRoomName(value);
        } else if (value === null && item === "roomName") {
          console.error("value is null", null);
        }
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

but when I log the value it's always null. It always falls into else if condition.[android studio logcat logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dnjz.png)